# Remove Test Email list from all email List of exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud, c#, fuel-sdk

I am using Fuel API sdk for Exact target integrateion with Asp.net web application I am getting all list of email campaign through this code.

```
 List<ET_Send> sendList = new List<ET_Send>();
            ET_Send s = new ET_Send();
            s.AuthStub = myclient;

 s.Props = new string[] { "ID", "CreatedDate", "ModifiedDate", "Email.ID", "SendDate", "EmailName"};
            GetReturn sGet = s.Get();
            foreach (ET_Send send in sGet.Results)
            {
                sendList.Add(send);
            }
            while (sGet.MoreResults)
            {
                sGet = s.GetMoreResults();
                foreach (ET_Send send in sGet.Results)
                {
                    sendList.Add(send);
                }
            }
```

I want to remove Email which is send as Test Email.
How can I achieve this ,pLease help

Comment: Just to make sure I understand... you want to get all the ET_Send(), that have not been sent as a Test Send?